# L_q matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, interpolation

The following arose out of studying $\ell_q$ Lewis weights. Let $P$ be a real $n \times n$ orthogonal projection matrix (i.e., $P$ is symmetric and $P^2 = P$) and let $W$ be the diagonal matrix consisting of the diagonal elements of $P$, so $W_{ii} = P_{ii}$ for $i \in [n]$.

Let $1 \le q \le 2$. Prove (or disprove) that for all vectors $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that $\|PW^{\frac12-\frac1q}v\|_2 \le \|v\|_q$, equivalently that $\|PW^{\frac12-\frac1q}\|_{\ell_q \to \ell_2} \le 1$.

Comment: Since it's true for $q=1$ and $q=2$, it should be true for all $1\le q\le 2$ by the Riesz--Thorin interpolation theorem.

Comment: Do you have a proof that applies the Riesz-Thorin theorem to prove the statement? I do not see a way to apply it.

Comment: By substitution, your inequality can be rewritten as $\| P W^{1/2} v \|_2 \le \| W^{1/q} v\|_q$, and $\|W^{1/q}v \|_q=\| v \|_{\ell_q(W)}$. So, what is needed to prove is $\|PW^{1/2}\|_{\ell_q(W)\to\ell_2}\le1$.

Comment: $W^{1/2-1/q}$ isn't even defined if $q<2$ and $W_{ii}=0$ for some $i$.